# Usernames exposed by login attempt?

Tags: webauthn, fido

I'm trying to expand my application to support WebAuthn login. So far, I have successfully set up a test application (using this https://github.com/lbuchs/WebAuthn PHP implementation) on my local server.

I think I mostly understood the process now, but I have a security question: When you use WebAuthn as the only authentication factor (which is supposed to be possible), the user only enters his desired username and gives his credentials by a fingerprint or his YubiKey or something. In this diagram (https://developers.yubico.com/WebAuthn/Libraries/Using_a_library.html), it is said that the server returns a list of credentialIds associated with the username. The authenticator then answers the challenge to which it has a private key.

My problem is: If an attacker wants to find out which usernames exist, he could try to provide different usernames and test if the server returns any credentialIds. Isn't this a security issue? Usually an attacker should never gain any information from a failed login attempt.

Answer (score 4):

It will be made possible by the "Resident Credentials" as soon as the browsers and **FIDO2**-hardware widely support it, as described [in this blog post](https://medium.com/@herrjemand/introduction-to-webauthn-api-5fd1fb46c285#2bd3).

Meanwhile, you could store the user ID in a long-live cookie or in the browser (`localStorage` API). Preferably you should store opaque identifier because of the risks of leaking. Unfortunately, the data can be flushed out of the browser (user action, browser update...) and are less persistent than Resident Credentials.

Comment: Agreed - "resident keys" should be used and the parameters to `navigator.credentials.get()` should have an empty `allowCredentials` array - i.e. not leak any data about the user or whether they may or may not exist. This also means you don't even need to prompt for a user name as that can be stored on the device too at the point of registration using the `requireResidentKey` option. When you initiate the challenge the browser/OS UI will prompt them to selected a device and account.
I believe this is already supported in all major browsers apart from iOS Safari (which I'm sure is coming soon)

Comment: Another option may be to return dummy credential IDs for inexistent accounts. This way an attacker may not be able to distinguish between a registered and un-registered username. Still, this would be tricky to implement right, since those credential IDs would have to be generated in a pseudo-random way, perhaps based on the username. Otherwise the attacker can make two requests (maybe from separate IPs) and check if the credential IDs change. Besides this, worrying about username enumeration for login is not worth it if it is possible to do it with the registration form. And most times it is.